# UWP Json.Convert storage files

Tags: c#, json, local-storage, uwp

I am making a UWP app in which I am trying to save storage files picked by user to the local settings by serializing them, and I want to deserialize them and use them again when I want to. it saves IReadOnlyList object to the local settings just fine, but at the time of deserializing it gives and exception, that this method cant return storage files because it doesnt have a constructor for this, something like this. I am posting the code of my both methods of saving and loading data. please see it and help me...

```
    public static void SaveState<T>(string key, T value)//save method
    {
        //key is provided by me so that i can use it to load the data later.
        var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

    public static T LoadState<T>(string key)//loading data
    {
        var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))//exception occurs on the below line
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(((string)localSettings.Values[key]));
        return default(T);
    }
```

and I use these methods as follows:-

```
    var files = StateService.LoadState<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>>(Playlist);
    //StateService is the class which has these static methods...
```

Note: when i try to load data with a key which has no data against it in the local settings, it doesnt give any exception and just returns an empty list.but when its supposed to return a filled list of IReadOnlyList then it gives and exception...

Comment: You should put the exception that you get.

Comment: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Windows.Storage.StorageFile. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].ContentType', line 1, position 16.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` tries to instantiate `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>` but interfaces cannot be instantiated... you should use for example `List<StorageFile>` as T for setting and reading the list...

Comment: i will try List<StorageFile> instead of IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> and let you know of outcome thanks :)

Comment: i tried what u said still getting the same exception , i am pasting the text of exception below

An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Windows.Storage.StorageFile. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].ContentType', line 1, position 16.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Ah yes, you cannot store StorageFile in settings

Comment: ... you need to add the StorageFile to the FutureAccessList and store the token in the settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227171

Comment: yes i knw tht i can do tht and it works 100 percent but it is limited to 1000 files that is a problem, i was looking to store them somewhere else where there is no limit

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that before and I had the same problem. I did different approach instead of trying to save the StorageFile I saved the json content with the key and always my data is in string ( the json data) and I can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` without problems.